# How to convert jbyteArray to native char* in jni?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to convert a jbyteArray to native c string (char*) in jni? Unfortunately I can't find any documentation on how to do that. I'm invoking a java function with the following prototype in the c code.

```
public static byte[] processFile(byte[] p_fileContent)
```

In the c code I am invoking this function which is returning a byte array. The content of this byte array is a java string. But I need to convert it to a c string.

```
jbyteArray arr = (jbyteArray) env->CallObjectMethod(clsH, midMain, jb);
printf("%s\n", (char*) arr);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe you would use `GetByteArrayElements` and `ReleaseByteArrayElements`. Something like:

```
boolean isCopy;
jbyte* b = GetByteArrayElements(env, arr, &isCopy);
```

You should be able to cast `b` to `char*` at this point in order to access the data in the array. Note that this may create a copy of the data, so you'll want to make sure to release the memory using `ReleaseByteArrayElements`:

```
ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, arr, b, 0);
```

The last parameter is a mode indicating how changes to `b` should be handled. `0` indicates that the values are copied back to `arr`. If you don't want to copy the data back to `arr`, use `JNI_ABORT` instead.

For more details see the [JNI Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#interface_function_table).

Comment: @DRH Updating a 1.4.2 link to a 1.5 link isn't much of an improvement.

Comment: Careful will null termination. In general, file contents won't be null terminated; C(++) string functions might choke on that. In order to reliably work around that, you'd have to copy the file bytes into a buffer one byte larger, and set the final byte to zero

Comment: `ReleaseByteArrayElements()` must be called even if there was no copy operation involved

Comment: I used this way but the size of jbyte is very lower than the jbytearray element. For example arr size is 16384 but when I convert it to jbyte the size of jbyte is 8. Anyone has a idea about it?