# Android JNI - Load dlib shape predictor file

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, dlib

With a normal Visual Studio C++ project i use the following code to load a shape predictor file into dlib shape_predictor variable:

```
    dlib::shape_predictor spredictor;
    //calling the file with a relative path
    dlib::deserialize("sp68fl.dat") >> spredictor;
```

However, using JNI in Android, i load this file from my activity and pass it as an byte array. So i have a jbyteArray which is the shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat file used for face detection with Dlib.

I found an overloaded method deserialize(serializable_type& item, std::istream& in) but can't figure out how to use it (maybe i have to convert jbyteArray to this istream).

How can i load this file to the dlib::shape_predictor from the jbyteArray?

EDIT:

This is what i have tried so far:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <dlib\image_processing.h>
#include <dlib\image_processing\frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib\image_processing\render_face_detections.h>
#include <dlib\image_processing\generic_image.h>
#include <dlib\image_processing\full_object_detection.h>
#include <dlib\opencv.h>
#include <dlib\geometry.h>
#include <dlib\image_transforms.h>
#include <dlib\serialize.h>
#include <dlib\gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib\image_io.h>

extern "C" {
struct membuf : std::streambuf
{
    membuf(char* begin, char* end) {
        this->setg(begin, begin, end);
    }
};


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_br_edu_infnet_test16_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject daobj,
                                                     jbyteArray fileBytes,
                                                     jint fileSize) {
    dlib::shape_predictor spredictor;

    jboolean isCopy = true;
    jbyte * a = env->GetByteArrayElements(fileBytes, &isCopy);
    char* teste = (char *) a;

    std::ifstream in;
    //stream is not loading? stream size is zero after read method
    in.read(teste, fileSize);

    try {
        dlib::deserialize(spredictor, in);
    } catch (dlib::serialization_error &serializationError) {
        //deserialize method fails. Dlib error: deserializing object of type int
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << serializationError.what();
    }

    in.close();
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(fileBytes, a, JNI_ABORT);

    const char *cppString = "Diego";
    jstring javaString = env->NewStringUTF(cppString);
    return javaString;
}
}
```

The activity sending the byte array:

```
package br.edu.infnet.test16;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
//        tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
        byte[] buffer = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("sp68fl.dat");
            int size = inputStream.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();
            stringFromJNI(buffer, size);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERRO", "DEU EEEEEEERRO: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public native String stringFromJNI(byte[] fileBytes, int fileSize);
}
```

Looks like the problem is that ifstream is not being loaded using variable teste, which is a char pointer. This file has approximately 100MB size.

Answer (score 3):

You could open the file in C++. The catch is that in Android you need full path to the file name, no *current directory* that you can rely upon. It may be easier to use Java APIs to prepare the full path and pass the string to C++ instead of sending the buffer.

If that's impossible, you must convert the **jbyteArray** to **char[]** (see *[How to convert jbyteArray to native char* in jni?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8439341/192373)*), and then create a **std::istream** as in *[Get an istream from a char*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782037/192373)*.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I couldn't get the deserializer to work using neither istream nor ifstream. I have tried using istream with the suggested membuf struct, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I only granded permission to read and write on storage and worked.
Try add on manifest:

And call for the permission

requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION);

I saved the files on root and used the absolute path to located.